# Remove Specific Information from a String - PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a php script for work, I've got most of it figured out and spent hours,
trying to get this working. Here's the deal. I've got this information.

```
</i>xxxx at \<a href=\"http://xxx/xxx/xxxx/11205xxx3887\" data-hovercard=\"/ajax/xxxx/xxx.php?id=112054175xxx3887\">xxxxx\</a>\</span>\
```

Ofcourse i'm trying to format this to be readable, something like,

```
xxxx at xxxxx
```

problem is the url changes constantly or i could just use a easy substr or something.

Any suggestions???

Comment: Use [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags).

Comment: why not use actual values instead of confusing 'xxxxx' or 'xxx' text?

Comment: Providing several example of actual strings would provide people with more to work with in assisting you with an answer.  Dont forget to select the best answer if one has already been provided and give upticks to those that are close but not the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my best attempt. It would be helpful if you could provide a larger section of code to work with, and if you could explain what the `xxxx` stands for it would make it much easier to solve your problem. Are they characters, numbers, times, prices? And do you know the origin of all the kooky forward slashes? Very unsettling...

I used the code as it was provided, so you may want to watch out for the last trailing `\`.
When I copied your code into my text editor it pasted as `\n` rather than `\`.

```
$string = "</i>xxxx at \<a href=\"http://xxx/xxx/xxxx/11205xxx3887\" data-hovercard=\"/ajax/xxxx/xxx.php?id=112054175xxx3887\">xxxxx\</a>\</span>\\";

$modified_string = trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($string)), '\\');

echo $modified_string;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the the following:

```
$str = strip_tags($str);
```

See [php.net/strip_tags](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)